# Linux отказывается выполнять команды и запускать приложения

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

При удалении python столкнулся с проблемой. Половина приложений не хотят запускаться, при этом в консоли следующий текст

```
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: неверный интерпретатор: нет такого файла или каталога
```

Повторная установка python не помогает. Snap пакеты со стора также не устанавливаются

Comment: так python3 надо установить

Comment: установите ровно то, что удалили.

Comment: когда я пытаюсь установить python, то он не может установить python из-за того, что не установлен python

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть из-за того, что в системе стоит python2, но версия по умолчанию указана python3.

попробуй использовать **update-alternatives** чтобы изменить дефолтную версию.

Сначала уточни какие версии стоят, а затем примерно так:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2
```

Цифра в конце означает номер в списке.
И затем в интерактивном режиме, выбираем нужную версию следующей командой:

```
update-alternatives --config python
```